# HAProxy Backend ACL: can i resolve a hostname and use the ip address to authorize the connection?

Tags: haproxy

we use haproxy for multiple backends that sometimes needs to be accessible only from intranet, so the in the backend configuration i use this:

```
backend srv-web-http-dev_ipvANY
    mode            http
    id          105
    log         global
    timeout connect     30000
    timeout server      30000
    retries         3
    acl         INTERNAL_LANS   src 172.1.0.0/16
    acl         INTERNAL_LANS   src 172.2.0.0/16
    acl         INTERNAL_LANS   src 172.3.0.0/16
    http-response allow  if  INTERNAL_LANS
    http-response deny 
    server          srv-web-01 172.1.2.3:888 id 117 check inter 1000  resolvers
```

Now, a third party developer should connect from the outside and he asked me if i could resolve a dns query to get the ip to be authorized, as he use dyndns to get the right ip as he roam across the country.

```
For example: record A mynameisdev.devdomain.com -> 101.102.103.104
```

And get 101.102.103.104 authorized to connect to the backend srv-web-http-dev_ipvANY.

I checked on the haproxy docs and i can't see how i could get this to work. Seems that there isn't a method to resolve a dns query and use the resulted ip in the ACL check (for the backend section)

Answer (score 0):

As you don't show the output of `haproxy -vv` we don't know which HAProxy version do you use. Therefore Link I here the latest version from the doc.

You can use [do-resolve](http://docs.haproxy.org/2.9/configuration.html#4-do-resolve) to resolve an IP.

Partly copied from doc and untested.

```
resolvers mydns
  nameserver local 127.0.0.53:53
  nameserver google 8.8.8.8:53
  # some more config for resolvers section

frontend fe
  bind 10.42.0.1:80
  http-request do-resolve(txn.myip,mydns,ipv4) src
  http-request capture var(txn.myip) len 40
  # more config

backend srv-web-http-dev_ipvANY

  # more config 

  http-response allow  if  { var(txn.myip) -m ip 101.102.103.104/32 }

  # more config
```

That's the link to the [resolvers section](http://docs.haproxy.org/2.9/configuration.html#5.3.2)